# How can I start a local multiplayer game?

Tags: rocket-league

How can I start a couch multiplayer game in Rocket League? Can't seem to find out how.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This answer is for PS4, but I expect it works similar on PC.

While in the main menu, there is an indicator in the lower left corner telling you which local players have connected already. It also tells you "Press options to join". After every local player has joined this way (pressing the options/start button), you can simply start an exhibition, seasons or online match (except ranked) and your couch buddies will join automatically.

Tip: You can also disable bots by selecting "No bots" as difficulty in the match settings.

Comment: Can confirm this for PC. You can connect up to 4 XBox Controllers to the PC which can be used to play a local multiplayer game. Each player has to press Start on his controller to join.

Comment: Can confirm. Only thing that doesnt Work is having one player on Keyboard/Mouse